# bootgrid with empty fields

Tags: javascript, jquery-bootgrid

i use bootgrid for displaying info in table.
Data for table is always random and sometimes some fields are missing.
Simple example:

```
ID;SELLERENTERPRISEID;BUYERBRANCHID;PRODUCTID;EAN;PRODUCTNAME;VERPACKUNGSEINHEIT;SOLLBESTAND;UEBERBESTAND;LOCKED;RIGHTS;
336;79763;;72216;404;Untertasse 12 cm;6;;0;0;3;
187;79763;;90032;440;SalatschУМssel, rund 19 cm;1;;0;0;3;
79;79763;;90039;440;Mini-Krug 0,50 l;1;;0;0;3;
331659;79763;;999;999;;999;0;0;0;3;
```

and screen for these data

[image]

for last row third field is empty, but table got value from previous line.
If use sorting for this table, it looks more terrible:

[image]

so missing fields for last three rows are from first line.

Could someone explain me, how to fix this problem.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A bug was in php function for data parser.
Thx!